# Not able to connect to private blob using Python SDK from VM

Tags: python-3.x, azure, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

I am trying to connect to private blob using python SDK from linux VM.Both blob and VM are in same virtual network.

code used

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient,BlobServiceClient
service_client = BlobServiceClient(url,sas_token)
container_client = service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='Inbound/Canvas/Extraction/')
for blob in blobs:
    # split filename and the path
    blob_name = blob.name.rsplit('/', 1)
    print(blob_name)
```

error

```
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fbbf7de5070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: This is a DNS issue. Your VM should be able to resolve the A records in privatelink dns zones.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if you are passing the invalid URL. Make sure to pass **Blob service SAS URL** like below:

Make sure to Generate the **SAS Token and URL** with required permissions:

[image]

When I passed the **Blob service SAS URL**, I am able to get the list of Blobs successfully like below:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient,BlobServiceClient

account_url = "Blob service SAS URL"
sas_token = "SasToken"

service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url,sas_token)
container_client = service_client.get_container_client("container_name")
blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='ruk')
for blob in blobs:

blob_name = blob.name.rsplit('/', 1)
print(blob_name)
```

[image]

You can also make use of **Connection String** to get the blobs like below:

[image]

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient,BlobServiceClient
service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("ConnectionString")
container_client = service_client.get_container_client("container_name")
blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='ruk')

for blob in blobs:
blob_name = blob.name.rsplit('/', 1)
print(blob_name)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The issue was with name resolution , I have added FQDN with IP address into /etc/hosts file .